# Yoast Seo Plugin meta title not showoing

Tags: plugins, seo, plugin-wp-seo-yoast

I am using latest wordpress 4.5 and latest version of Yoast seo plugin. I have filled all the options of yoast seo on page like focus keyword, seo title, meta description etc. But when i view the source code of my page, it is missing the tag `<meta title>` my source code is like this

```
<!-- This site is optimized with the Yoast SEO plugin v3.1.2 - https://yoast.com/wordpress/plugins/seo/ -->
<title>Orlando Family Law Attorney Providing Caring Representation</title>
<meta name="description" content="The right family law attorney makes all the difference in your divorce case. We focus our representation on achieving your goals and helping you grow."/>
<meta name="robots" content="noodp"/>
<link rel="canonical" href="http://chrissprysenski.com/practice_areas/family-law-attorney/" />
<meta property="og:locale" content="en_US" />
<meta property="og:type" content="article" />
<meta property="og:title" content="Orlando Family Law Attorney Providing Caring Representation" />
<meta property="og:description" content="The right family law attorney makes all the difference in your divorce case. We focus our representation on achieving your goals and helping you grow." />
<meta property="og:url" content="http://chrissprysenski.com/practice_areas/family-law-attorney/" />
<meta property="og:site_name" content="Christopher M. Sprysenski P.A." />
<meta property="og:image" content="http://chrissprysenski.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/09/Family-Law.jpg" />
<meta property="og:image:width" content="500" />
<meta property="og:image:height" content="334" />
<meta name="twitter:card" content="summary" />
<meta name="twitter:description" content="The right family law attorney makes all the difference in your divorce case. We focus our representation on achieving your goals and helping you grow." />
<meta name="twitter:title" content="Orlando Family Law Attorney Providing Caring Representation" />
<meta name="twitter:image" content="http://chrissprysenski.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/09/Family-Law.jpg" />
<!-- / Yoast SEO plugin. -->
```

how can i add meta title back, please suggest me. Thanks

Comment: Everything looks good. What kind of the `<meta title>` you want?

Comment: Welcome to WPSE. A quick note, third party plugins are off topic for this site, so your question may get closed by a moderator. The best place to ask any Yoast SEO questions is either through the plugin support forum at Wordpress.org, or any support facility Yoast offers on their website

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is only `<title>` which is present in your example. 
`<meta title>` DOES NOT exist as far as I know :)

Comment: happens to me too :)